# Bootstrap expand collapse issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [tabCollapse](https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse) plugin it's make my tab to accordion on responsive (768px) but I want my all collapse be expand using jquery - my jquery my code is like this:

```
$(".collapse").show();
```

this code works on console but in my project it doesn't work

[click to see demo](http://codepen.io/aguko/pen/bdEzya)

Comment: what error you are facing ?

Comment: this code is not work except console..why

Comment: and I want my all collapse be expand doesn't matter how it's happend

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(".collapse").collapse("show")
```

and

```
$(".collapse").collapse("hide")
```

Comment: Then try using this example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h maybe you missed to add something... If this example doesn't help then I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: but tab structure is chancing after responsive I guess that's why it doesn't work and yes my example works just chrome console :/